# ListView in ConstraintLayout not displaying

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-constraintlayout

Been knocking my head for hours trying to figure out what am doing wrong with this. I have a ListView in a ConstraintLayout that isn't being displayed. I am just getting accustomed to using ConstraintLayout so u'll forgive me for any silly mistakes. These are my layout files

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/noteList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The ListView in the above file doesn't display at all but when I substitute the ListView with a RecyclerView, the list is displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/noteList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong with the ListView that makes it not work and yet RecyclerView works fine?

Comment: Why are you setting **layout_width** and **layout_height** to `0dp`? Could that be your problem? I will go with `match_parent` or _wrap_content` according to your needs

Comment: Do you use the same layout for the rows of the ListView respectively the RecyclerView? Please add the layout for the rows as well. BTW both ViewGroups do work differently: for example a height of `match_parent` in a ListView row will be changed to `wrap_content`under the hood whereas in a RecyclerVIew it will really cause the item to fill the whole screen

Comment: @sebasira tried adjusting the layout_width and layout_height to match_parent and wrap_content but still got no results.

Comment: @BömachtBlau Yes i do. It still doesn't display both in the design view in Android Studio preview and the app after me running it.

Comment: @pirupius : Try putting listview direct in activity_main.xml and just check are able to view? Don't use include for testing puprpose

Comment: I have tried it in my computer, and the ListView displayed correctly, I copied your code, and just changed the version of widgets, then removed the themes because they doesn't find. So maybe your other code is wrong, for example the ListView's rendering code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preview your ListView in design mode, you'll have to use the `tools` namespace. 
Add something like this to your XML file; 
 `tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"` 
Then add the `tools` namespace to the top of your XML file like so; 
 `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

So, your file should look like this;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/noteList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

That way you'll be able to preview your list view.